# Openshift says Quota limit reached

Tags: mongodb, openshift

In the Open shift i have 4 projects and 25Gb of space allocated to the projects.
And db i use is Mongo Db(3.2 Version).

So in openshift iam getting the message has Quota limit reached and if i check all the 25 GB has been used as per openshift

But in Mongo db if i check using **db.stats()** for all the projects i have used 5.7GB

I want to know where the remaining space is used Or how to find exact space that i am using.

Comment: The quota applies to the reservations of the complete persistent volumes, not how much you use of them.

Comment: How can know how the 25 GB is used and how to get the calculations

Comment: How many persistent volume claims have you made? What was the requested storage size for each? Run ``oc get pvc`` to see what has been claimed. You can also see them listed under storage in the web console. You will need to do that in each of your projects. Is it possible you have made persistent volume claims that you never subsequently deleted when you were done with them?

Comment: I have never made a persistent volume claims.Will the route folder in mongodb consumes the space..? But still there is 20 GB difference i can find.

Comment: Since you were talking about such a large amount, was assumed you were talking about storage. Include in your question the output from running ``oc describe quota`` and ``oc describe appliedclusterresourcequota``. They show quotas and what is used. Which shows output will depend on how your cluster is configured.

Comment: Actually with the commands that you shared i can see the limit and usage .Now i have a ABC project which has 8gib limit and used is 4gib but for this project in mongodb if i check using db.stats() actually used is 1.2 Gib only .But in Openshift portal it shows used is 4gib.How is that possible.. and where is the remaining space consumed.(Is the remaining space consumed for read write operations in mongodb..?)

Comment: Are you talking about storage or memory? Either way, the quota relates to what you have reserved that you can use up to. It doesn't matter whether you use it all up, that it is reserved to you is what takes away from your quota.

Comment: I am talking about the storage not memory. Actually the memory is allocated separately for all the projects and storage is allocated separately .

Answer (score 0):

I think you’d like to do double checks about your resource issues.

- check what resource limit was reached, is it a storage?
- you should check the event logs which provide more details.
- check what quota limits were configured your cluster or project.
- have you been experienced some troubles after the showing the messages? Such as db hanging up, no response from pod and so on.

They are just troubleshooting guides, but i hope it help you.

Comment: Yes the storage limit was reached were i did not even use 20% of the storage. If i check in mongodb  through db.stats() the storage i have used is 1.7Gb but in open shift portal it shows 8Gib storage is used. Why is it showing has 8Gib is used.